# Conditional Mapping in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I have created a simple job in Talend that will perform an inner join in the data between 2 excel sheets and then dump the result in an output excel sheet. This can be best illustrated by the below diagram :-

[image]

The mapping used in tMap is :-

[image]

However the additional challenge  for me now is that I have to perform this mapping only if the column value in that row is not NULL. eg there is a mapping row1.RECID = row2.RECID, but this should only be legal if row2.RECID is not NULL.
How do I achieve this in Talend? I have experimented a lot with tMap expressions but can't get it right..

Here is a small sample input and it's corresponding expected output.
Suppose my input has values :-
v1, v2,v3,v4
1 , A, O, 3 
2, B, X, 4 
3, C, X, 4

and lookup has values

v1, v2, v3 
1, A, O, 3
2, null, X, 4
3, null, C, 4
2,null,X,null

Then the output should be :- 
v1,v2,v3
1,A,O,3
2,B,X,4
2,B,X,4

Comment: You are using the correct settings, the inner join model will gives you the non-null values, if you get something else please add current output sample and the desired output to your question.

Comment: Why you dont filter input rows that have null in v2 column ? so tmap will receive all the rows of the main input and only the first row of the lookup and gives you the desired output.

Comment: @5413d -> Yep, tried that way but it became too tedious.. Is'nt there a more elegant approach to this?

Comment: I didnt understand why the last line appear, can you please explain the last two lines of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before joining your input flows, you have to reject rows with null values, I have created a mapping based on the given simple data.

[image]

Comment: @5413d -> Great idea! But I wish to check this on multiple columns. How can I apply such a filter to each and every mapping and make it independent of the other column's mappings?

Comment: @Sparky just write in the filter box at the bottom, `row2.v1!=null and row2.v1!= "" and row2.v2!=null and row2.v1!=""`, you can write any logical expression to filter your data

Comment: @5413d -> I tired putting the conditions below but it wasn't giving me the correct output. But finally I go the solution , I performed a self join with my input table and also joined the input table with my tmap table. Then for each joining condition I put a condition as : row.col1.equals("NULL")?out2.col1:row.col1.. It's working perfectly fine now....

Comment: @Sparky Im happy for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to map the maximum of values from row1, the put row2 with left outer join.

I you want values which are only in row1 and row2, you can add a filter in row2 for that (but I guess that this is not what you want)

Comment: Thanks, but yes my requirement is different.. Have highlighted a sample case in the question..

Answer (score 0):

Talend does have a more elegant option that will allow the filtering of your data on multiple columns.  Use the **tSchemaComplianceCheck** component where filtering out nulls and empty is as simple as clicking a couple of check boxes.  This allows you to use your own schema to check against nulls and empty values and filter them out.  The error rows go to a reject flow which you have the option of processing.  If you do not wish to capture and process the rejects you can simply ignore them.  Your main flow will only have the records that passed the compliance check.  Here are some tips on using it:

- In the tSchemaComplianceCheck component -->Basic Settings Screen click **Custom Defined** and it will show you each column.  Make sure **Nullable** is unchecked or else it will allow nulls to pass thru.
- In the Advanced Settings tab check **Treat all empty string as NUll**.  This will work in conjunction with the prior step to filter out both null and empty.
- In your Excel component, click Advances Settings tab, and check **Stop reading on encountering empty rows**.

below is a screen shot which shows the basic flow and setting.  You would link to a tMap instead of the tLogRow.   If I have understood your problem correctly I think you will find this is the ideal solution in Talend.

[image]

Comment: @E LaRoche -> Thanks this is indeed a great component for filtering.. but what I really want is a way to implement conditional mapping. As in if the particular field in lookup file is NULL then the mapping should not be considered dynamically! The component you mentioned would hep me in a manner similar to my current Implementation using tFilterRow.. but how can I change my mappings dynamically at run time based on the lookup file values of current row?